# Android StringBuilder can't append

Tags: android, limit, stringbuilder

I'm trying to append to a string using Stringbuilder. Unfortunately after a certain number of characters the Strinbuilder doenst append anymore.

I tried this simple code:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0;i<=9999;i++){
        sb.append("c");
    }
```

When I log with LogCat and count the "c"s that have been added (It should be 9999) its only 4069!

I'm using Eclipse with the Android emulator. As far as i can tell, no related Exception is thrown.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you counting them in the logcat output or using .Length()?

Comment: You don't show how you are using logcat, but what if you just print to the log sb.length()

Comment: try `System.out.println(sb.toString().length());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max length of logcat messages is just under 4k (4096 bytes - some overhead), so you seem to be logging the `c`s and counting them from the truncated logcat message.

```
#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_LEN        (4*1024)
#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_PAYLOAD (LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_LEN - sizeof(struct logger_entry))
```

Comment: You're right! Pretty stupid of me :(

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Just to be clear, System.out.println typically gets re-directed to logcat (Log.i()), which is why the System.out falls under these constraints.